# HashMultimap Guava Java, problems getting collection from key value

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, guava

Hopefully I understand the purpose for the HashMultimap in Guava, because if I don't, I'll just downvote myself.

I'm trying to access the Collection from a specific key where the key is a class like so...

```
public class Coords {

private int[] coords;

public Coords() {
    coords = new int[2];
}

public Coords(int x, int y) {
    coords = new int[] {x, y};
}

public void set(int x, int y) {
    coords = new int[] {x, y};
}

public int x() {
    return coords[0];
}

public int y() {
    return coords[1];
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    Coords o = (Coords) obj;

    return Integer.compare(x(), o.x()) == 0 && 
           Integer.compare(y(), o.y()) == 0;
}
```

When I compare two Coords objects with the same integer values in it's array, I get true.

When I popular the HashMultimap with key/value pairs, I do indeed get a unique set of keys, but I do not get a collection of more than one Item. I get multiple keys that seem to be identical, even though I have overridden the equals() method in Object. When I popular the map...

```
HashMultimap<Coords, Item> items = HashMultimap.create();

        Item s = new Item();
        s.coords.set(0, 0);
        Item w = new Item();
        w.coords.set(0, 0);

        Item p = new Item();
        p.coords.set(1, 1);

        items.put(s.coords, s);
        items.put(w.coords, w);
        items.put(p.coords, p);

        Collection<Item> bucket = items.get(s.coords);
        bucket.add(s);
        items.putAll(s.coords, bucket);

        bucket = items.get(w.coords);
        bucket.add(w);
        items.putAll(w.coords, bucket);

        bucket = items.get(p.coords);
        bucket.add(p);
        items.putAll(p.coords, bucket);

        for(Coords key : items.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key.x() + " " + key.y());
        }
```

I get the output...

```
0 0
1 1
0 0
```

What am I missing? Did I implement something incorrectly?

Comment: You need to override hashCode too. Your equals method is never being called because equal Coordinates objects have different hashCodes so are being put into different buckets.

Comment: public int hashCode() { return Arrays.hashCode(coords); }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments. I actually realized I need to overwrite the hashCode() method shortly after I posted this question. Of course...

But I will explain, for those of you who are stuck on this problem, and don't understand how to implement hashCode() successfully. This question has answers very similar to mine...

[Does hashcode implementation of Java Arrays.hashcode() uniformly distribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788292/does-hashcode-implementation-of-java-arrays-hashcode-uniformly-distribute)

But, I ended up implementing hashCode() like this...

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 1;
    for (int e : coords)
        hash = 31 * hash + e;

    return hash;
}
```

Thanks to cpp beginner, I could have used Arrays.hashCode(), but just thought I'd write out something so that I could see it working. So I could better understand the method and what it does.